# Upload direto para amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-aws, symfony-2, heroku

Trabalho utilizando Symfony 2.5, hospedagem Heroku e Amazon S3 para os arquivos estáticos. Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde o usuário poderá subir imagens muito grandes, e isso acaba travando o servidor do meu app ou dando timeout pois o servidor não consegue completar a transferência das imagens.

Penso que a melhor solução seria uma transferência direta do arquivo para o S3, mas nunca fiz isso e não quero me arriscar sem pensar um pouco a respeito.

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria exatamente isso, permitir que o usuário faça upload de arquivos diretamente para seu bucket no S3. Depois disso basta usar um bundle ou uma lib para poder ler os arquivos que estão lá.

Esse texto faz uma abordagem bem interessante a respeito disso: https://florian.ec/articles/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-symfony2-and-gaufrette/

Comment: também utilizo gaufrette o problema é que agora não vou mais realizar uploads com PHP somente com javascript, e isso me parece muito propenso a falhas pois vou ter que subir o arquivo no S3 e depois atualizar meu app, sem falar que eu vou ter que ficar assinando todas as requisições feitas para a amazon.

Comment: Você pode usar um bucket público para upload dos arquivos. Além disso, se seu bundle estiver bem configurado, as requisições para o S3 a partir da sua aplicação ficam bem simples.

Comment: em um bucket público qualquer pessoa pode ficar subindo arquivos ?

Comment: Sim, leia aqui: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html Entretanto, ainda acho que é melhor tentar achar uma solução de upload para a sua aplicação (que colocaria o arquivo no bucket) do que permitir acesso público.

Comment: Sim, acho que vou aumentar o tempo limite do meu script PHP nessas requisições para escapar dessas complicações. Muito obrigado @rodrigo-rigotti

Comment: Acho melhor limitar o tamanho do upload para as imagens, não acha?

Comment: é um requisito do sistema suportar grandes tamanhos de imagens

Answer (score 0):

Então pelo que eu percebi, você está tendo problema com seu servidor como você mesmo disse. A melhor sugestão que eu posso dar é fazer com que os arquivos não passem pelo servidor. Acho que a melhor implementação que poderia fazer era subir o arquivo via Ajax, diretamente pelo HMTL mesmo.

Assim usaria do recurso multipart para estes arquivos grandes que iria enviar. E caso precise tratar os arquivos você pegaria diretamente no bucket.